# Go program compiles but returns wierd error when is run

Tags: url, go, google-url-shortener

So i am new to Golang (started learning it today) and i have been writing a URL shortener however after running `go install` and then running the compiled program from the CLI it returns this error:

```
2014/04/05 19:05:27 invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
exit status 1
```

code refrence: https://github.com/hullswitch/urlshortnr

Answer (score 1):

You problem is caused by your request to Google URL Shortner. It returns a 404 Error with HTML body instead of JSON. You could debug it adding `log.Println(string(output))` to `if` handling `err` after the `Unmarshal`.

Comment: i will try that - ok so the API is not found :/ i guess its just a malformed link or something